# Bootstrap grid system breaking the flow with huge gaps between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

as you can see in the image, when some column is a little bit smaller, the other ones tend to break the flow and let huge gaps between them, just fixing after the broke row. How i'm supposed to make it jump down even when under smaller columns(and still have the effect like it's mixed between the sizes?)

[image: Bootstrap grid system breaking the flow with huge gaps between columns]

---

I wanted something like this effect:

[image: Wanted effect]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Also see this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527674/bootstrap-3-responsive-panel-layout-with-varying-heights/22532971